# How do I select an individual radio button in a generic function?

Tags: jquery

I've a few forms where I need to show and hide some questions based on responses to particular questions. Instead of having to write a lot of repetitive code, I'm trying to write a generic function.

It works for select options but not for radio buttons. I added a commented console.log statement where the issue occurs. I don't know how to select the radio button the user clicks, instead of all radio buttons. In a custom code, I'd use $(this) and that'd work, but not sure how to generalise.

In this example, if #q1 is 'yes' then 'q2' and 'q3' should be show, otherwise be hidden. And if #a is set to '1' then #b and #c should show, otherwise be hidden.

https://jsfiddle.net/mskppbjL/

HTML:

```
<div id="q1">
  Question 1
  <select>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="q2">
  Question 2
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<div id="q3">
  Question 3
  <input type="radio" name="q3" value="0">0
  <input type="radio" name="q3" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" name="q3" value="2">2
</div>



<div id="a">
  <input type="radio" name="q3" value="0">0
  <input type="radio" name="q3" value="1" checked>1
  <input type="radio" name="q3" value="2">2
</div>
<div class="b">b</div>
<div class="c">c</div>
```

JS:

```
function set_related(element, value, related) {

  var element = element,
    value = value,
    related = related;

  function display() {
    console.log($(element).val());  // always returns 0 because not $(this) element but all 
    if ($(element).val() == value ? $(related).show() : $(related).hide());
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    display();
    $(element).change(display);
  })

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  set_related($("#q1 select"), "yes", $("#q2, #q3"));
  set_related($("#a input[type='radio']"), "1", $(".b, .c"));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

Your function call for radio button should be

```
 $("#a input[type='radio']").click(function() {
  set_related($(this), "1", $(".b, .c"));
  });
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mskppbjL/2/)

Comment: I did think of that and had tried. It doesn't show/hide 'b' and 'c' as you click on radio buttons. So that didn't work.

Comment: That works, thanks. Maybe that's the only way round this, though it's quite a bit to write out for each question to use a generic function. I'm thinking there's probably a neater way to write out the whole code with OOP structure, but that's beyond my skillset at the moment..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `type` attribute to select a radio button on, and the `checked` pseudo-class for the selected element, for example;

```
$('#q3 input[type="radio"]:checked');
```

In a function you want something like;

```
$('#q1 input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 'yes' )
    {
        $('#q2').show();
        $('#q3').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#q2').hide();
        $('#q3').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: That'd work if I custom code each one, but not in generic function.